# Add iCSee to Java project

Tags: java

I come across this for the first time. I want to know if anyone has done this. I need to add an iCSee camera to my project. To get started, I downloaded the iCSee application and connected to the camera using my phone. Connection is via WIFI. How can I use the camera in my project? Where to begin? Thanks.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GOAerJGqRY
```

Comment: I'd begin by looking for some documentation, api and/or sdk. :)

Comment: Please note that you should post what exactly you did so far to tackle your problem (besides installing some application - which one btw - and using it): did you do any research, did you run into specific problems, etc. - Also please note that posting a youtube link without any explanation might not be the best approach - at least I wouldn't open it.